# Difficulties with putting numpy array in multiprocessing queue

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, pickle

I have parameter sets in numpy arrays that I feed into a multiprocessing queue, but they are garbled when received in the worker. Here is my code to illustrate my issue and question.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES = 2

def worker(input, output):
    for args in iter(input.get, 'STOP'):
        print('Worker receives: ' + repr(args))
        id, par = args
        # simulate a complex task, and return result
        result = par['A'] * par['B']
        output.put((id, result))

# Define parameters to process
parameters = np.array([
    (1.0, 2.0),
    (3.0, 3.0)], dtype=[('A', 'd'), ('B', 'd')])

# Create queues
task_queue = Queue()
done_queue = Queue()

# Submit tasks
for id, par in enumerate(parameters):
    obj = ('id_' + str(id), par)
    print('Submitting task: ' + repr(obj))
    task_queue.put(obj)

# Start worker processes
for i in range(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES):
    Process(target=worker, args=(task_queue, done_queue)).start()

# Get unordered results
results = {}
for i in range(len(parameters)):
    id, result = done_queue.get()
    results[id] = result

# Tell child processes to stop
for i in range(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES):
    task_queue.put('STOP')

print('results: ' + str(results))
```

With numpy 1.4.1 and Python 2.6.6 on a 64-bit CentOS computer, my output is:

```
Submitting task: ('id_0', (1.0, 2.0))
Submitting task: ('id_1', (3.0, 3.0))
Worker receives: ('id_0', (2.07827093387802e-316, 6.9204740511333381e-310))
Worker receives: ('id_1', (0.0, 1.8834810076011668e-316))
results: {'id_0': 0.0, 'id_1': 0.0}
```

As it is shown, the tuple with the numpy record arrays are in good condition when submitting the tasks, but are garbled when the worker receives the arguments, and the results are incorrect. I read in the [`multiprocessing` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#all-platforms) that the "arguments to the methods of proxies are picklable". From what I can tell, the numpy arrays are perfectly picklable:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> for par in parameters:
...     print(pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(par)))
...     
(1.0, 2.0)
(3.0, 3.0)
```

My question is why the parameters are not correctly received in the worker? How can I otherwise pass a row of a numpy record array to a worker?

Answer (score 1):

numpy arrays should be pickle-able (I think) but here you're actually dealing with numpy.void instances which, I'm not sure why, don't seem to be pickle-able.

If you do:

```
for par in parameters:
    print(type(par))
    print pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(par))
```

You get:

```
<type 'numpy.void'>
(-1.3918046672290164e-41, -1.3918046679677054e-41)
<type 'numpy.void'>
(-1.3918046672290164e-41, -1.3918046679677054e-41)
```

One way to work around this is to apply `parameters = parameters.reshape([-1, 1])` to make your (N,) array into an (N, 1) array. That way when you loop over parameters, you'll get arrays of size 1 which will hopefully pickle just fine. Hope that helps.

Comment: Looks like your issue was a bug, fixed in this commit https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/971bab3d51726b95f5afe0c22cbbd7983023f626

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem with you, but my condition is a little differnt with you.

Originally, I output a number every loop in my subprocess and combine them into numpy.dnarray. Finially, I pass the array to Queue, but My main process can't start after I run p.join().

Old codes it's like this below

```
# subprocess
for i in range(n):
    array[i] = data[i]
queue.put(array)
# main process
queue.get()
```

However, I change another way to handle such problem such like this

```
# subprocess
for i in range(n):
    queue.put((i, data[i]))
# main process
for i in range(n):
    while queue.empty():
        i, data = queue.get()
        array[i] = data
```

Briefly, I just split my data into smaller part(data, position) and pass them to the queue, and the main process receive the data sync.
I hope it would help